# Ampps, PHP 7.1,Windows 7 ( The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.)

Tags: phpmyadmin, windows-7, ampps

Install Ampps 3.8 on windows 7. The default PHP version is 5.6. PHPMyAdmin runs normally. when I change the PHP version to 7.1 and try to access phpmyadmin it shows following error

phpMyAdmin - Error
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

I checked following and they are already enabled

`extension=php_mbstring.dll`
`extension=php_exif.dll`
`extension=php_mysqli.dll`

extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\Ampps\php-7.1\ext" and restart apache and MySQL but same result

Please help if anyone know the solution

Comment: Do you see the mbstring extension when running a phpinfo() under PHP 7.1? See https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

Comment: Yes i can see it

Multibyte Support enabled

Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
oniguruma version 5.9.6
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
Multibyte (japanese) regex support enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 5.9.6

Comment: Maybe you are using an older phpMyAdmin version. On https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ we see that phpMyAdmin 4.9.1 is compatible with PHP 5.5 to 7.3.

Comment: Phpmyadmin ver.4.9.0.1 
it works with PHP 5.6 this happens when change to PHP 7.1

Comment: mbstring is not supposed to be required in phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1. I did not have a look at the code, however https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html does not mention mbstring as being required. Maybe report an issue about this at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues.